# Is it possible in django forms to leave Filefield empty?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am defining a Form class which has a filefield and is not mandatory to add a file to it...but whenever i do not provide  a file the form is invalid....so is there any way by which i can make it optional for user to add a file or not???

Comment: Are you sure form is invalid because of filefield? If so, are you sure it has `required=False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible, so check if you have required=False.

Quoting from documentation for django 1.4: "By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you pass an empty value -- either None or the empty string ("") -- then clean() will raise a ValidationError exception:" ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#required )

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are basing your form on a model, what you want is [`Field.blank`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) - this allows a field to be blank. (Potentially you will also want [`Field.null`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) too, which allows a blank value to be recorded as `null` in the database).

```
x = FileField(..., blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Even if Karan doesn't use any model? :-)

Comment: @DrTyrsa The question explicitly states a `FileField` is being used.

Comment: Well, this is what I get for answering Django questions when I still havn't used it much, I'll prefix it with a disclaimer.

Comment: It gives a TypeError that 'code'__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'

Comment: @Karan It's my mistake, as DrTyrsa pointed out, I presumed you were basing your form on a model, which you are not, so it's different. I'll leave my answer up as it could still be a resource to another person.

Comment: For form without a model just `required=False` is enough. `allow_empty_file` will allow empty file but the field will still want some file.

Comment: @DrTyrsa I have given required = False but then it raises a MultiValueDictKeyError...key 'file not found in MultiValueDict

Answer (score 1):

forms.py

```
myfile = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

Comment: Could you add some comments on what this does and why it solves the problem?